# show submenu click and fix

Tags: css, menu, fixed, submenu

This is my  **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59yTX/)**

Hover works fine, but I want to show the sub menu when i click on an option locks the submenu and then if hover on the main menu,  display sub menu options but to stay on the other,

any help?

```
<div id="cssmenu">

<div class="divul">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a>Buscador</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Busqueda Datos</a></li>
                <li><a>Estadisticas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a>Clientes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Buscador Clientes</a></li>
                <li><a>Nuevo Cliente</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">
            <a>Incidencias</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Nuevo Incidencia</a></li>
                <li><a>Buscador Incidencias</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

```
    #cssmenu{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #278204;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}


#cssSubmenu{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 30px;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/ 
}

#cssmenu ul{
    height: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #278204;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}


.divul{
    background: 
        url(/CI_Gestion_incidencias/images/menuL.png) left no-repeat,
        url(/CI_Gestion_incidencias/images/menuR.png) right no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 29px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}


#cssmenu ul li
{
    height: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/**




**/

/*#cssmenu li a {
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

*/
#cssmenu li:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#cssmenu li ul {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    display: none;
    height: 25px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.95;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;

    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;

}




#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu li li {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    display: inline;
   /*  float: none;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;*/
}



    #cssmenu li li:active {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        display: inline;
    }


#cssmenu li ul a {
    color: #000;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You need to use jQuery for this, There is no css solution for the same like hover!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want show on click then use jquery.

You can try below code:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/59yTX/1/)

```
$('.has-sub a').click(function(){
  $('.has-sub ul').hide();
  $(this).next().show();

});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works fine but if I click on any option of the submenu disappears and only disappear would be nice if I click on any option from the main menu

Comment: You mean hide only click on main menu link not on sub menu link?

Comment: works well but when i click on any option of the main menu the page content disappear. is there any way to prevent refresh the page? I've tried <a href = "javascript: return false" but chrome console returns this: 

XMLHttpRequest can not load javascript: return. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabindex="0"` in HTMl and `:focus` in CSS together: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59yTX/2/)**

`<li class="has-sub" tabindex="0">`

```
#cssmenu li:hover > ul,
#cssmenu li:focus > ul{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: this works as long has first level <a> are not link (href attributes) , else it catches the click event. a work around then has to take place